# ERPNext frontend customization

Tags: frontend, web-development-server, erp, erpnext, frappe

I have just recently installed ERPNext and I wanted to customize/rebrand the frontend of some pages. For example I want to put in an overlay sidebar on the Asset Dashboard page (http://localhost:8000/app/dashboard-view/Asset). But I cannot find the html file which I should edit to make the necessary changes.

I tried to search for it everywhere but cannot find it. ChatGPT tells me it is located in erpnext/erpnext/assets/doctype/asset/ but there is no html file there, only js, json and py files.

I am using ERPNext version 14 btw. The entire installation was smooth and I did not have any problems at all.

Is it even possible to do something like this and rebrand the pages or am I stuck with the default pages given to me by the app?

Answer (score 0):

As of v15, it is not possible to completely customize a page.

However, you can add your logos and customize the header and footer of the landing page by going into the website settings.

ERPNext doesn't allow customizations to make sure that the system follows a consistent design system.